# Acumatica SalesOrder endpoint with LineDetails

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to get the LineDetails with the get of a salesorder.
entity/defaultext/20.200.001/SalesOrder$expand=details&$top=100

With the expand=details I see the details object, but that doesn't contain all the "Line Details" from the screen.

How do we get the "Allocations" to come through as well? What I really need is the serial / lot number for  each line detail entered.

[acumatica sales order object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zlv1W.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "that doesnt contain all the line details from the screen" I assume not all the columns? You need to go to the "Web Service Endpoints" screen and add them. Be sure to click on the "Detials" sub tree item of "sales order" if you want to add details columns

[image]

The allocations tab is already a sub view of the details grid, you can expand it by using $expand=Details,Details/Allocations, and you can add any neccecary columns there the same way as you can at the details level.

Comment: The expand Details/Allocations was exactly what I was looking for. I was trying Details,Allocations with no luck. Thank you!